# Spinner with on Click Listener

Tags: java, android

I am using spinner that shows error when i am trying to extract the item id of the selected spinner item.
My Code goes here:

```
public void dispspi()
  {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adap= new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, level);

      spinner.setAdapter(adap);
      spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

            p=item;
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });
  }
```

How to get the item id of the spinner? Any help is appreciated..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IIRC, you should be using a selected listener, not click:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
```

Then you can add the override tag to your selected method.

Comment: Thanks, brother.

Answer (score 9):

```
private String selecteditem;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{    
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {

  selecteditem =  adapter.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
   //or this can be also right: selecteditem = level[i];
} 
  @Override     
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
{         

 }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int postion, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  SpinerValue3 = parent.getItemAtPosition(postion).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "You have selected 222 : " + SpinerValue3,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use some `OnItemSelectedListener` for work with selected item. But sometimes we would like to handle exactly click for spinner. For example hide keyboard or send some analytics etc. In this case we should use `TouchListener` because `OnClickListener` doesn't work properly with Spinner and you can get error. So I suggest to use `TouchListener` like:

```
someSpinner.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->  onTouchSomeSpinner(event)}

fun onTouchSomeSpinner(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            view.hideKeyBoard()
            ...
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you should have this in the listener(OnItemSelectedListener)

```
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

It might works without it but put it to be consistent 
but there might be other errors also, can you provide the error log ?